# Open Cover Having No Finite Subcover

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Information:

> Consider the open cover $\mathscr{F}=\begin{Bmatrix}\pmatrix{0,5-\frac{1}{n}}:n\in\mathbb{N}\end{Bmatrix}$ for the set $(0,5)$.

Question:

> Is $(0,5)=\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}\pmatrix{0,5-\frac{1}{n}}$? Why does $\mathscr{F}$ have no finite subcover?

Comment: It would seem that if you take any interval out of the infinite union you'd still cover $(0,5)$.

Comment: But what happens if you only consider finitely many?

Comment: OK, so since no finite subset of $\mathscr{F}$ can possibly cover the infinite set $(0,5)$, we say that "$\mathscr{F}$ has no finite subcover over $(0,5)$," right?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, do you know what the TAPI pipeline is?

Comment: Not quite. A finite number of sets can cover an infinite set, just not in this case.

Comment: Yes, I meant in this case of course.

Comment: yes. So how do you prove it in this case?

Comment: Suppose $\mathscr{G}$ were a finite subcover. Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ be the largest $N$ such that $\pmatrix{0,5-\frac{1}{N}}$ is in $\mathscr{G}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, choose a rational $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $5-\frac{1}{N}<q<5$. This contradicts that $\mathscr{G}$ covers $(0,5)$.

Comment: @JSchlather, you're weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathscr{F}$ is an open cover of $(0,5)$; it is **not** a cover of $\{(0,5)\}$.

1. Yes, $(0,5)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(0,5-\frac1n\right)$. On the one hand it’s clear that $\left(0,5-\frac1n\right)\subseteq(0,5)$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(0,5-\frac1n\right)\subseteq(0,5)$. On the other hand, if $x\in(0,5)$, then $x<5$, and $5-x>0$. Thus, there is a positive integer $k$ such that $\frac1k<5-x$ and hence $x<5-\frac1k$, so that $x\in\left(0,5-\frac1n\right)\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(0,5-\frac1n\right)$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $(0,5)$, it follows that $(0,5)\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(0,5-\frac1n\right)$ and hence that $(0,5)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(0,5-\frac1n\right)$.
2. Let $\mathscr{F}_0$ be any finite subset of $\mathscr{F}$, say $\mathscr{F}_0=\left\{\left(0,5-\frac1{n_k}\right):k=1,\ldots,m\right\}$. Let $n=\max\{n_1,\ldots,n_m\}$; then $5-\frac1{n_k}\le\frac1n$ for $k=1,\ldots,m$, so $$\left(0,5-\frac1{n_k}\right)\subseteq\left(0,5-\frac1n\right)$$ for $k=1,\ldots,m$. This implies that $$\bigcup_{k=1}^m\left(0,5-\frac1{n_k}\right)=\left(0,5-\frac1n\right)\subsetneqq(0,5)$$ and hence that $\mathscr{F}_0$ does not cover $(0,5)$. That is, no finite subset of $\mathscr{F}$ covers $(0,5)$, i.e., $\mathscr{F}$ is an open cover of $(0,5)$ with no finite subcover.

Comment: The professor [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=real%20analysis%20harvey%20mudd%20compact&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQtwIwAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DzeVA74yivyg&ei=CUMxUv4c4auIAufXgMAO&usg=AFQjCNEc1xxTvQPIcJpRjVTTCAx7K78oxg&bvm=bv.52109249,d.cGE) use $\{(0,5)\}$ to mean $(0,5)$.

Comment: See my $\mathscr{G}$-argument in the comments below my question.

Comment: @SecureSpace: I doubt very much that any Harvey Mudd professor makes such an elementary mistake. That lecture is more than an hour long; if you give me a time stamp for a point at which you think that he’s made that mistake, I’ll take a look. In the meantime, I strongly suspect that he’s used $\{(0,5)\}$ correctly, to mean the set whose only member is the open interval $(0,5)$. This is of course a finite open cover of $(0,5)$, though not a very interesting one.

Comment: @SecureSpace: Yes, the argument with $\mathscr{G}$ works fine, though there’s no need to pick a rational number: any number in $\left[5-\frac1N,5\right)$ will do fine. In fact, you can simply use $5-\frac1N$.

Comment: 00:15:14, let me know if you're still in doubt.

Comment: Oh, wait. What a blunder, yes quite different.

Comment: @SecureSpace: Yes, it’s what I thought: the cover $\{(0,2)\}$ of $(0,2)$ consisting of the single set $(0,2)$. Okay now?

Comment: yes, sorry I doubted you. Wait, when you say "historical linguistics" what do you mean? Anyway, I'm reading a book now called *Language* by Bloomfield. If you haven't already read it, I'd recommend it.

Comment: @SecureSpace: No problem; I’m just glad to get it cleared up.